# Spring Batch step not committing transaction immediately

Tags: transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, batch-processing

I configured step to read and validate data. If any validation fails,I am updating error table(created to track file details) status as failed and reason as validation message(BatchFileDetail is error table in below code).
once saved this in DB, immediately I am throwing exception based on error table status

below is my code

```
    @Bean
    public Job fileParserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("fileParserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(validateFileStep())
                .build();
    }

    public Step validateFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateFileStep")
                .tasklet(fileTasklet)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(dontRollbackOn=BatchServiceException.class)
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws 
    Exception {
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
        BatchFileDetail batchFileDetail = new BatchFileDetail();
        batchFileDetail.setFileId(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        batchFileDetail.setFileName(resource.getFilename());
        batchFileDetail.setStatus("STARTED");
        batchFileDetail.setProcessedOn(new Date());
        CommonUtillity.validateBatchResource(resource, StringConstants.FILE_NAME, batchFileDetail);
        validateBatchFileDetail(resource.getFile(), batchFileDetail);
        batchFileDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(batchFileDetail);
        if(CBOSConstants.FAILED.equals(batchFileDetail.getStatus())) {
            throw new BatchServiceException(batchFileDetail.getReason());
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

But data what i saved in error table is getting roll backed. Handling exception leads to proceed with another step but i want to terminate current job with entry in error table.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the logic to save error to the error table is within the same transaction rolledback ?

Comment: yes. I added inside same transaction to interrupt current job execution flow

Comment: Whatever is written to database in that transaction will be rolled back together . You will need to separate out the logic to save error from the transaction

Comment: I separated by configuring another step and its working as expected. But, I want to do it in the same step

Comment: I cannot answer without fully understanding your code. You can try this , you can annotate the method to save error to db with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` so that a new transaction will be started for the same. Make sure the call to this method is not an internal call.

Comment: If you could share the code logic where to save the error status , a complete solution can be arrived at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which i found may not best, but as per time being i proceeds with below.

```
@Bean
public Job fileParserJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("fileParserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(validateFileStep())
            .next(validateFileStatusStep())
            .build();
}

public Step validateFileStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateFileStep")
            .tasklet(fileTasklet)
            .build();
}

public Step validateFileStatusStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateFileStatusStep")
            .tasklet(validateBatchFileDetailTasklet)
            .build();
}

FileTasklet.java
-----------------
@Override
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn=BatchServiceException.class)
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
    BatchFileDetail batchFileDetail = new BatchFileDetail();
    batchFileDetail.setFileId(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    batchFileDetail.setFileName(resource.getFilename());
    batchFileDetail.setStatus("STARTED");
    batchFileDetail.setProcessedOn(new Date());
    CommonUtillity.validateBatchResource(resource, StringConstants.FILE_NAME, batchFileDetail);
    validateBatchFileDetail(resource.getFile(), batchFileDetail);
    batchFileDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(batchFileDetail);
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

}

ValidateBatchFileDetailTasklet
------------------------------
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    BatchFileDetail batchFileDetail = batchFileDetailRepository.getRecentFailedTransactionStatus(StringConstants.FILE_NAME);
    if(StringConstants.FAILED.equals(batchFileDetail.getStatus())) {
        throw new BatchServiceException(batchFileDetail.getReason());
    }
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

With this solution, First error table getting updated with failure status and failed reason then transaction commits in one step. In next step fetching recent record based on file name and checking status of fetched record. If it was `FAILED`, throwing exception to terminate current job.

In case of status is not `FAILED` only, next data has to be processed. If status was `FAILED`, we have to terminate current batch job.

Answer (score 1):

You are annotating your tasklet with `@Transactional(dontRollbackOn=BatchServiceException.class)`. This is not how tell Spring Batch to not rollback a transaction for a given exception type.

Your tasklet will be executed in the scope of a transaction controlled by Spring Batch which you can customise through the transaction attributes, see [AbstractTaskletStepBuilder#transactionAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/AbstractTaskletStepBuilder.html#transactionAttribute-org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttribute-).

So in your case, you should be able to implement your requirement by removing the `@Transactional` on the tasklet and define your step with something like:

```
@Bean
public Step validateFileStep() {
    TransactionAttribute transactionAttributes = new DefaultTransactionAttribute() {
        @Override
        public boolean rollbackOn(Throwable exception) {
            return !(exception instanceof BatchServiceException);
        }
    };

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateFileStep")
            .tasklet(fileTasklet)
            .transactionAttribute(transactionAttributes)
            .build();
}
```

This is for a simple tasklet. For a chunk-oriented tasklet, it is possible to do that with a [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noRollback(Class)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#noRollback-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: Thanks Ben for your valuable answer, found there is a way to deal trasaction. But this transaction attributes inserting record repeatedly until we terminate manually. In my case i have only one record and its continuously saving in db.

Comment: That's another story, you can stop the step with `chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setTerminateOnly();` before throwing the exception. But in hindsight, throwing an exception is not the best way to address your problem. I would let the tasklet finish (without throwing an exception and trying to avoid rolling back the transaction) and set the exit status of the step to FAILED instead (with `chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);`.

Comment: As per my scenario, Status means its ```status``` column of error table i.e, ```BatchFileDetail``` in example. In one transaction entry should save in error table then current running job should aborted(if status column value is failed). By throwing exception job is aborted but entry saved in error table is getting roll backed.